# How parse a text after some word with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, parsing, numbers

I need to extract all numbers after "vertex", but my regular expression `(?<=vertex)\s((-?\d*\.?\d+)\s*)*` return one last number.

Text template:

```
vertex
144.64329 -65.95227 -40.5391
244.25595 -77.64196 -51.07746
144.64738 23.13064 -40.53168
244.26259 67.13464 -51.0654
144.64968 -65.94874 36.17572
244.26407 -77.63749 46.41944
```

How to get all numbers after "vertex"?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Delphi XE (pcre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex flavour support `\G` metacharacter, try with:

```
(?<=vertex\s)-?\d*\.?\d+|(?<=\G\s)-?\d*\.?\d+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aT0oR5/2)

- `(?<=vertex\s)-?\d*\.?\d+` - positive lookbehind for vortex word and space, followed by numbers,
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G\s)-?\d*\.?\d+*` - positive lookbehind for previous match followed by numbers

Another approuch would be to match all numbers with:

```
(?<=vertex)(?:\s?-?\d*\.?\d+)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aT0oR5/4)

then split matched string with `\s`